# SQL format date from insert

Tags: mysql, visual-foxpro, dbf

I have a dbf file converted to SQL. The date format for sql is  YYYY-MM-DD. but the dbf date format is MM-DD-YY. Is there a sql function that will return a YYYY-MM-DD format ? like

```
INSERT date_in VALUE(FUNCTION('09-16-14'))
```

Or is there a way to change the format form the .dbf? I'm viewing the dbf from DBF Viewer 2000

Comment: The date format stored in a `.dbf` file is `YYYYMMDD`.

Comment: The way you see a date in a viewer has nothing to do with the internal storage mechanism. You should be able to pass a VFP date directly to SQL, assuming the VFP field is actually a Date field and not a character field holding a date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert a string to a MySQL DATE or DATETIME literal:

```
INSERT date_in VALUE(STR_TO_DATE('09-16-14', '%m-%d-%y'));
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

use DATE_FORMAT()   Displays date/time data in different formats

```
INSERT date_in VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(date,format))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(myVal, '%d.%m.%y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```